# Passing keys to Full Screen game c++

Tags: c++, directx, game-development, autorun

So I'm trying to create an autowalk/run program for dayz. The current script I have seems to work for sending the 'w' key to anything except dayz. How would I go about making a run script or modifying my current code?

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

void pressW(bool x){
   INPUT ip;



   ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
   ip.ki.wScan = 0x57;
   ip.ki.time = 0;
   ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

   ip.ki.wVk = 0; //Hex code for 'W'
   ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE; //Press the key down ?
   SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(ip)); //Use function

   Sleep(10); //Sleep so it doesn't spam the key press


   //ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; //Release the key
   //SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(ip)); //Use function
}
void releaseW(){

}

int main()
{
    bool run = false;
    while(true){
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)){run = !run;}

            while(run){
                pressW(run);
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_HOME)){run = !run;}
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote [this AutoHotkey script](http://resources.3ventic.eu/holdW.ahk) for autorunning.